# How to extend type from a library in TS?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I use a [useTheme](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#using-the-current-theme-in-your-own-components) hook `import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'` from `react-navigation` lib that returns `colors` object that is a type of `Theme`.

```
type Theme = {
    dark: boolean;
    colors: {
        primary: string;
        background: string;
        card: string;
        text: string;
        border: string;
        notification: string;
    };
};
```

In a file, where we have all layout/styles related stuff, I have extended it with one more property:

```
interface ITheme extends Theme {
  colors: Theme['colors'] & {
    textSecondary: string;
  };
}
```

How do i type cast it somehow it to a library type once, so the `colors` object that is returned from `useTheme` hook will become `ITheme` custom type anywhere i call this hook?
It gives me `Property 'textSecondary' does not exist on type '{ primary: string; background: string; card: string; text: string; border: string; notification: string; }'` error so far.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I would create a custom hook what adds the `textSecondary` property and use that hook throughout the application.

Comment: I 100% agree with Roberto

Comment: sounds like a good idea, yeah, will do